# How to get the compiler used in common lisp?

Tags: common-lisp

How to get the compiler used in common lisp?

example imaginary:

```
(defun get-compiler ()
    (RETURN-COMPILER-NAME))

(defun some-factory ()
    (cond ((string= (get-compiler) "SBCL") (some))
               ((string= (get-compiler) "CMU") (some))
               ((string= (get-compiler) "MCL") (some))
               ((string= (get-compiler) "EXCL") (some))))
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `lisp-implementation-type` (see the [manual](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_lisp_i.htm)):

```
CL-USER> (lisp-implementation-type)
"SBCL"
```

or

```
CL-USER> (lisp-implementation-type)
"Clozure Common Lisp"
```

Note that the function returns the name of the implementation, which is not necessarily a compiler. Some Common Lisp implementations can include an interpreter, a compiler, a translator to another programming language, etc.